# Как обезопасить удаление файлов на сервере?

Tags: безопасность, php, защита, уязвимости, upload

Здравствуйте!

Пользователь имеет возможность загружать файлы на сервер и так же их удалять.
Удаление файлов происходит запросом Ajax - передачей полного пути к размещенному на серверу файлу.

Как обезопасить удаление файлов?

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, вы занимаетесь каким-то самоистязанием, ей-богу. Ну возвращает путь и пусть возвращает, почему его-то надо использовать? Почему не возвращать вместе с путём айдишник? Есть же вполне рабочая и оптимальная схема, а решение с использованием пути - заранее неоптимальное и не совсем рабочее (можно искать в базе и по пути, чего здесь пока никто не предложил, но [вот что](http://i.imgur.com/NK3J99h.jpg) я по этому поводу думаю), чего вы так к нему цепляетесь вместо того, чтобы за пятнадцать минут просто прокинуть этот айдишник и сделать все по-человечески?

Comment: А если будет подмена ID файла на удаление? Вопрос более глубокий с точки зрения безопасности сервера.

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, я напишу капсом, для экспрессиновсти

ТО ТОГДА МОЖНО БУДЕТ ПО ID И СЕССИИ ВЫЧИСЛИТЬ, ЯВЛЯЕТСЯ ЛИ АВТОР ФАЙЛА ТЕКУЩИМ ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЕМ, ЧТО ПОЗВОЛИТ СООТВЕТСТВЕННО ПРЕДОТВРАТИТЬ ТАКИЕ СЛУЧАИ. ОТМЕЧУ, ЧТО ПРЕДОТВРАЩЕНИЕ ПРИ ЭТОМ ОБОЙДЕТСЯ РАЗ В ПЯТЬДЕСЯТ ДЕШЕВЛЕ, ЧЕМ ПРИ ПЕРЕДАЧЕ ПУТИ. АЙДИШНИК, ПУТЬ - ЭТО ВСЕ ПРОСТО ИДЕНТИФИКАТОР ФАЙЛА, КОТОРЫЙ НИКАК НЕ ЗАЩИЩАЕТ И, НАОБОРОТ, НЕ ОТКРЫВАЕТ ДОСТУП К УДАЛЕНИЮ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Начать хранить список загружаемых юзером файлов в БД, удалять по ID файла, с проверкой прав на удаление

Comment: Так там и хранится список, и там же есть ID.
Представьте картину - юзер загружает картинку и тут же ее удаляет крестиком. Так вот нужно удалить из папки

Comment: >Так там и хранится список, и там же есть ID. Представьте картину - юзер загружает картинку и тут же ее удаляет крестиком. Так вот нужно удалить из папки

Так зачем вы светите полный путь?

>Права на удаление - это что вы имеете ввиду?

Да, чтобы юзер не свой контент удалил.

Comment: Путь и так для любого пользовательского файла засвечен, скажкм изображения. В моем случак ajax возвращает путь к загруженной картинке, чтобы отобразить превью, а так же отправить этот путь при сабмите формы на добавление. Сейчас проверка лишь на авторизацию пользователя в системе,  нужно на уровне сервера обезопасить

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант, выделять каждому юзеру собственную папку, напр. по его id после авториазции. Загруженные файлы помещать только в нее, и путь для удаления считать относительно этой папки. Запретив "вылезать" из нее.

Comment: Как запретить вылезать из нее? Скажем, чтобы не было случая с путем: /path../
_____

Можно удалять по хэшу файла, тогда его корректность проверять запросом в базу, оттуда уде вытягивать правильный путь к файлу и улалять, но не хочется делать лишний запрос в бд.

Comment: Запретить вылезать – запретить любые символы в названии папок, кроме слешей и `[a-z0-9_-]`, - регулярными выражениями проверять.

Плюс этого метода с папками — горизонтальная масштабируемость позже: подключаете другие диски, скажем, и например, чётные id на старом диске, нечётные на новом.

Answer (score 0):

Опять же, как вариант, - сделать папку-корзину с подпапками для каждого пользователя, куда будет падать то, что пользователи удаляют. Для пользователей это равноценно удалению, для вас - нет.

Всё, что вам нужно, - мониторить корзину.